# formula field in flow

Tags: visual-workflow

Formula fields in flow.

I have created a formula field of Concatenation of 3 variables used in a flow which are text fields.

This formula field is later used when creating a record.
Name field(type Text)  of one Object is assigned this value.

This is working as expected when i run the flow

I am getting an error when i trying to migrate the Flow to other instance
vaTestName (Formula) -  The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Number).

Answer (score 1):

Are you migrating "everything" including the objects at the same time? If the objects already exist, it sounds as though the formula field in the other instance has been defined as a number field instead of a text field. At least that's what the error message is telling you.

Have you checked the problem formula field in the new instance to see what data type it's set to hold?